# MEAN stack delete action is not done correctly. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: mean

Whilst doing a MEAN tutorial, I've got this fine code deleting articles from mongo (via mongoose)

```
    $scope.removeArticle = function(id){
        $http.delete('/articles/' + id)
            .success(function(data){
               console.log(data);
            });
        $location.path('/articles');
    }
```

The console.log prints me a nice 200,
but $location.path never happens, because something goes wrong on the server side. (errors are at the bottom)

Here is the routes/articles.js file that successfully catches the $http request

```
router.delete('/:id', function(req,res,next){
    var id = req.params.id;
    Article.removeArticle(id, function(err, article){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.location('/articles');
        res.redirect('/articles');
    });
});
```

and here is the models/article.js that successfully deletes the article from the db

```
module.exports.removeArticle = function(id, callback){   
    Article.findById(id, function(err, article){
        if(!article) return next(new Error('Could not load article'));
        article.remove(callback);
    });
};
```

My server log says this

```
DELETE /articles 200 120010ms
DELETE /articles 200 120008ms
DELETE /articles 200 120006ms
```

and my Chrome console says this

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/articles net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

and the tutorial concludes in this state. Anyone see what I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here, as far as I can tell from the code you posted, is the route is not actually handling the success. You should return a JSON object along with the status code to the client and not a redirect call.

The redirection on successful deletion should be handled on the client side but you need to place the call in the `.success` function because in some cases the location handler might be called before the `.success` has had a chance to finish.

Comment: That was it. Returned res.json(article), even though angular didn't need it, and the server was happy. Thanks!